# How to specify left over spacing in div with text?

Tags: css

Basically, what I'm currently making is a nav bar. What I am trying to do with my buttons is since the names of each button are different lengths, I would like to have the space left in between the text and the button equal for example:

(- is space)

+----Hello----+

I want another button, with different text, but with the same amount of space (-) left in the button. 
How could I do this?

So it would be like this:

+----This is another button----+

This is what I have so far:

```
.homelink {
min-width: 60px;
min-height: 30px;
background: #666;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
margin-left: 20%;
position: absolute;
user-select: none;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -15px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
```

}

```
.forumslink {
min-width: 60px;
min-height: 30px;
background: #666;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
margin-left: 30%;
position: absolute;
user-select: none;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
```

}

Lastly, how would I be able to separate these equally, I noticed my method does a terrible job at it.

Comment: You could use `padding: 0 10px 0 10px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what CSS padding is for. See runnable CSS/HTML below:

```css
input[type="button"] {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
#container {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="button" value="Hello" />
  <input type="button" value="This is another button" />
  <input type="button" value="3rd" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't not think about that!
How would I be able to separate them equally?
For example, I currently want to separate them by 10%, but it does not take into account the width of the buttons.

Comment: Sure, you can add a `margin-right: 10%;` to achieve your equal spacing between. See updated answer.